# SQL-Query PHP -Blog

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure that somewhere in the web this question has been already asked but i have not found it, because i don't know for what exactly i should search. So i will try to describe the problem:

I have a Blog written in PHP and a SQL-database, where i receive the needed data.

Each Blog entry contains 1 image and 1 text-field and has its own id.
To get this data i execute this query (pseudo-code) -> this is working fine:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT news.id, news.position, news_text.date, news_text.text, news_images.image
                    FROM news 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN news_text ON news.id=news_text.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN news_images ON news_images.id = news.id 
                    ORDER BY position") as $row){
                                                echo "{$row['id']}";
                                                echo "{$row['position']}";
                                                echo "{$row['date']}";
                                                echo "{$row['text']}";
                                                echo "{$row['image']}"; 
                                                }
```

Now the problem starts. I want to add a comment field, where users can add a message. So for each blog-entry there can be several comments (would probably be a 1:n connection). 
- I tried to add a foreach loop in a foreach loop (stupid) 
- I tried with several SQL-query but only get rubbish as a result 
- I don't see the logic how to connect the database news_comment with the others

Here is my simplified database:

[image]

Can someone give me a hint how i could solve this problem. Result should  be:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT news.id, news.position, news_text.date, news_text.text, news_images.image
                    FROM news 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN news_text ON news.id=news_text.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN news_images ON news_images.id = news.id 
                    ORDER BY position") as $row){
                                                echo "{$row['id']}";
                                                echo "{$row['position']}";
                                                echo "{$row['date']}";
                                                echo "{$row['text']}";
                                                echo "{$row['image']}"; 
           Here i get for each blog-entry the corresponding comments..            
                                                }
```

Thank you.
Misch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve comments in another one query (not in loop) using the same conditions as for retrieving news. So that after executing both queries you will have to arrays: news and comments.

Then you just need to take appropriate comments for each news item.
To do that you might need to rebuild comments array so that comment news_id will be an index of array where comments are stored.

Finally it'd look like this:

```
$news = [
    [
        'id' => ...,
        'position' => ...
        <so on>
    ]
];

$comments = [
    $news[0]['id'] = [<comment array>],
    <so on>
];
```

That's the way most framework use to have data bound in result set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try your way as soon as possible but i have another problem that prevent me of trying it for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of Alex(thx) and MulipleIterator. This is how it worked for me (maybe someone has a better solution).

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT news.id, news.position, news_text.date, news_text.text, news_images.image
FROM news 
LEFT OUTER JOIN news_text ON news.id=news_text.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN news_images ON news_images.id = news.id 
ORDER BY position") as $row)
  {
  $news_id[] = $row['id'];
  $news_text[] = $row['news_text'];
  $news_images[] = $row['news_images'];
  $values = new MultipleIterator();
  $values->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($news_id));
  $values->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($news_text));
  $values->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($news_images));
  } 

foreach($values as $value) 
  {
  list($news_text, $news_images, $news_id) = $value; 
    {
    echo '$news_text';
    echo '$news_images';

    foreach($db->query("SELECT comment FROM news_comment WHERE id = $news_id ") as $row)
      {
      echo "{$row['comment']}";
      }
    }
  }
```